# How many components are too many in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Take a "Contact Us" form as an example. I could just build the entire thing in one component, or it could be really decomposed: every text field is a component, submit button, etc .... How does one know how much form should be deconstructed and rebuilt as Components?

Comment: Trial and error. I usually start writing normally and once I see something that could be its own component I put it there.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you often have the option of introducing a named abstraction into a `render` method simply by sprouting a function rather than a whole new component.

Comment: I am using 2 principles for making components:
If something is being used 3 or more times, make a separate reusable component for it. 
If a component is becoming 300+ or 500+ lines, split it into smaller components considering its visual/functional role.
Here's a useful answer on Quora around the same topic https://qr.ae/pvgsfO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My rule is to **component-ize things that can and will be re-used** in your app, *either aesthetically or functionally*. If this is the only form you need it is probably not worth the overhead of converting each element to a component. But if you will have many forms consider making components.

Example reasons to component-ize your form elements:

- Special form field functionality (`InputEmail`: does front-end validation for email inputs)
- Styling (`SubmitButton`: always red, full width, etc.)

In bigger projects I have worked on this has worked out well. I have a set of customizable form components so I can build a styled form with complex functionality. Usually it will look something like:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Input default label="Email Address" type="email" validate={validateEmail} />
    <Input default label="Password" type="password" />
    <Button primary type="submit" />
</Form>
```

- `Form` performs general validation logic
- `Input` runs a `validateEmail` prop and renders the label
- You get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

This is ultimately up to personal preference and the complexity of your application, however the documentation's ["Thinking in React"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) article cites the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as a good method to break down your UI into components.

Also of note: one of the main reasons you would build using react is that it strongly favors modular components that can be re-used. Larger, more complex components tend to be harder to re-use. You could build an entire contact form in one component, but if you'd like to re-use an email input validator elsewhere, you may consider creating another component.

Anecdotally, I would say that in practice my react components are somewhere between 50-300 lines in length, with the top-level components being the largest and most complex.